# Why not charge $0.99 per question?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Sure, it might slap the Kumbaya open forum model in the face but how about charging $0.99 per question? The board gets a piece, the person who's answer is accepted gets a piece, and the moderators get a piece (maybe).

Won't this filter out some of the "poor quality" questions and make people think twice about actually trying out google or researching their own issue before posting?

Comment: Uh... you do realize this is exactly what Stack Exchange wanted *not* to be?

Comment: I think you'll find that the people who are willing to pay to have someone answer questions for them are actually the people who *aren't* willing to do simple web searches before posting questions and who *will* expect answers to just do their work for them, which makes for bad questiosn.

Comment: Actually, the reverse is true. If I am paying to ask a question then I can ask anything I want.

Comment: @hichris123 Actually, what Experts Exchange does, and what SE (self proclaiming itself to be the Anti-Experts Exchange) doesn't want to do, is charge to read the answers.  On EE you don't just need to pay to ask questions, you need to pay to see questions anyone else asked (or at least to see the answer to them).

Comment: @Servy - Fair enough, but at least you'll get paid for your aggravation.

Comment: @sangony People that answer SO questions don't do it for the money.  If was wanted to charge for the answers I provide on SO I'd charge a hell of a lot more than whatever fraction of $0.99 I'd be getting.

Comment: I don't like this idea.....but for what it's worth I'd make it make it $100.

Comment: @Servy More importantly: we're not here for the aggravation! Be it paid or unpaid

Comment: @sangony I was just pointing out that you're suggesting the equivalent of Google charging a user for every search they do, or converting Wikipedia to a pay-per-month site. Our site comes from the people, and we'd have nothing without them. Why are you trying to limit the people who make quality contributions on our site. I know there are a lot of bad users, but there's plenty of users who contribute more then they take. You're approach would be like one of those filters that only allow approved sites. You're suggesting SE change it's core values, mission statement, its services, and identity.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: He's not. He's suggesting filtering out the crap. Changing identity is what smart people do. Sticking with the same old crap is what dumb people do, and they do it to get evolved out of the gene pool, or in this case, get flooded with endless crap.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin - I realize that and agree with you on pretty much all your points. I also try to devote some of my daily time to help others out. My suggestion was more of tongue in cheek post because of some of the frustration I also have from time to time. SO got me from zero to where I am today and I will always be grateful to all the people who helped me out BUT obviously this is not the right place to share a bit of tongue in cheek humor as some people take it way too seriously.

Comment: @sangony I do admit that might have been a little bit over-"protective" (I often use bold to emphasize main points without remembering that people think of it as yelling) but I do stand my ground. I feel passionately about SE because, I owe all of my success so far to SE. I feel like when you charge people for using Stack Exchange, you demean the whole spirit of community.

Comment: @DeadMG This just isn't a way to filter crap. It's a way to reduce *all* content. Don't get me wrong, it'll make users research more. However, it'll defer lots of good users, too.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin - I understand and certainly hold no ill will at all. As I said, it was a little dark humor mixed with a pinch of frustration. Having metaphorically gotten the crap beaten out of me for this posting, i shall take my leave and vow not to post on this forum... sorry, I meant Q&A format style website (I'm looking at you rene :) for a looong time!

Comment: @Servy actually there are (were?) simple ways to read the answers on experts exchange, which I always thought was a ridiculous website anyways.

Comment: Then don't take money from Question asker, Let rich volunteers donate SO, so that it can be distributed among best answerers in an appropriate way!!

Answer (score 40):

No. As @hichris123 stated in the comments, this is exactly what SO did ***not*** want to be.

Answer (score -103):

I, for one, would certainly care a lot less about the low quality of the question if I was getting even a small payment for answering it, and questioners may take more care about spending their hard-earned cash.

Frankly, I think we should give it a *try*. Something needs to change.

Comment: Imagine all of the dishonest things people do to get Imaginary Internet Points.  Now imagine what they'd do if they were making actual hard currency instead.  You'd never, ever, ever, see a question closed, or downvoted.  Everyone would be downvoting every answer besides their own (creating socks to do so) making vandalist edits in other answers, anything to get their money.  You'd have people hacking into each other's accounts, Phishing attacks by clone sites, people chargebacking the costs of questions, etc.

Comment: Then, imagine all the help vampires who now feel ENTIRELY ENTITLED to have their massive code blocks debugged because "I PAID U 2 WAH WAH WAH." Nightmares. Nightmares for __days__.

Comment: @ThePhD If they want to actually pay someone to do work for they they *are* entitled to have people do work for them.  They might not be willing to spend what it would take to have non-trivial problems solved, but they'd be entitled to ask.

Comment: Ah, just make it so you have to have a gold badge in that tag to answer paid-for questions.

Comment: If I'm going to pay _anyone_ for their contributions to Stack Overflow, by the Lords of Kobol it sure ain't gonna be you.

Comment: @Servy: Even more reason for them not to bother posting non-trivial problems. Hard to see how this would in any way be good, even if it were not a giant troll.

Comment: Yeah cos gold badge = "you know what you're talking about" sure yeah okay

Comment: It wouldn't be *you* getting the payment, it would be Stack Exchange. If they did implement this, you really think they'd mail you a check for every answer you submitted? Right...